# SMTPAuthenticationError at /contacts/contact on sending an email in django

Tags: python, django

I am newbie to django learning django from a course by doing a realestate website in which user makes inquiry of every site shown in every website. Here I want to send email in this and I did as said in the video tutorial I am following and I wrote the code as follows
My settings.py is

## Email config

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER='glakshmi@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='1@st345'
EMAIL_USE_TLS=True
```

In the views.py

```
 # Send email
    send_mail(
        'Property Listing Inquiry',
        'There has been an inquiry for ' + listing + '. Sign into the admin panel for more info',
        'glakshmi@gmail.com', # This is the from email address
        [realtor_email, 'glakshmi.nyros@gmail.com'], # This is to email address means we are specifiying where should the email goes
        fail_silently=False
        )

    messages.success(request, 'Your request has been submitted, a realtor will get back to you soon')
    return redirect('/listings/'+listing_id)
```

getting error [image]